# Qt 5.3 Android get native screen rotation

Tags: android, qt, qt5

I have problem with getting default screen orientation
I not found any way to get this orientation from Qt code, but I found that android.provider.Settings.System.USER_ROTATION contains info that I need.
How I can get this property from Qt except running Java code?
http://community.kde.org/Necessitas/JNI
Maybe I can put value of this property from main java class to my Qt code? (I mean QtActivity.java)

```
user_rotation 0 -> ROTATION_0  
user_rotation 1 -> ROTATION_90  
user_rotation 2 -> ROTATION_180  
user_rotation 3 -> ROTATION_270
```

thanks for help

upd: I found interesting line in QtActivity.java

```
loaderParams.putString(APPLICATION_PARAMETERS_KEY, parameters.replace(' ', '\t'));
```

maybe I can load default screen orientation as parameters?
I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need java

```
    QScreen *s = app.primaryScreen();

    qDebug() << "nativeOrientation: " << s->nativeOrientation();
    qDebug() << "orientation: " << s->orientation();
    qDebug() << (s->isLandscape(s->nativeOrientation()) ? "nativeOrientation lanscape" : "nativeOrientation not lanscape");
    qDebug() << (s->isLandscape(s->orientation()) ? "orientation lanscape" : "orientation not lanscape");
    qDebug() << (s->isPortrait(s->nativeOrientation()) ? "nativeOrientation portrait" : "nativeOrientation not portrait");
    qDebug() << (s->isPortrait(s->orientation()) ? "orientation portrait" : "orientation not portrait");
```